# Why does VS force my build to x64?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, buildconfiguration

Before I build, I choose x86 (or Any CPU, too) in the Properties tab for the project.

I save these properties, and if I re-open the Properties tab it's back to x64 as the platform and target, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing a build configuration in Properties doesn't actually change the *active* build configuration. It only allows you to switch between the various build configurations that are defined for your project so that you can edit the settings for each of those configurations. It's only a configuration selector.

The easiest way to change the *active* build configuration is using the drop-down boxes on the toolbar:

[image]

Those commands should be present in your toolbar by default. If you don't see them, [follow these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k643651.aspx) to get them back where they belong.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `.csproj` file is not readonly.

Make sure that your changing the build target, not the configuration selector.